# Lettrine in Abstract - Strange Behaviour

Tags: article, lettrine

[image: Strange Behaviour]
Does anyone know why this strange behaviour is happening when using lettrine in the abstract environment in stock-standard article class?

The `parshape` seems to be repeating...???

Here is my code to reproduce:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{lipsum,lettrine,helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}

\def\t{The Cat Sat on the Mat}
\def\tt{\t\t}
\def\ttt{\tt\tt}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}
\abstract
    \lettrine{T}{his is a test}\ttt\ttt\ttt

    \ttt\ttt\ttt

    \ttt\ttt\ttt
\endabstract

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hmm lettrine perhaps ought to be more careful with grouping.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{lipsum,lettrine,helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}

\def\t{The Cat Sat on the Mat}
\def\tt{\t\t}
\def\ttt{\tt\tt}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    {\lettrine{T}{his is a test}\csname@restorepar\endcsname\everypar{}\ttt\ttt\ttt\par}

    \ttt\ttt\ttt

    \ttt\ttt\ttt
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

(It's not really safe to use `\abstract` `\endabstract` so i changed it back to environment, it happens to work here but would fail if for example `titlepage` option were used)